# Sort files starting with special characters like . or _

Tags: nautilus, files

Is it possible to sort files in Nautilus or in the terminal starting with special characters like "." or "_" ?

Comment: Guessing you want those files on top of a list like Windows does, the anwser is NO. On Linux, you will have to name them with `0_myfile`

Comment: I would like also to get hidden files and folders be displayed first. If I remember correctly, a few years ago Linux used to display them first with the command ls -la